# Where to study probability and natural language processing from?

Tags: nlp

I am a programmer and I am interested in Natural Language Processing. I studied it a bit in college, but it was years ago and anyway it wasn't enough for a good knowledge of the field. I'm particularly interested in Markov chains and n-grams, mostly to build something that would let me analyzes and collect data from texts of various kind.

I am aware of software libraries that do exactly this, but I wish to really understand the theory and the basics. So what I am really asking is for a book (or more than one) to study natural language processing. I know that there is a lot of probability theory involved, so I would also like to study probability from scratch, if you have something to suggest.

Comment: I would start with taking an online class on theoretical NLP. I guess, all online universities have such, for example, [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/course/nlp). Just google for "study nlp online". Schools usually provide with book references, both electronic and printed.

Answer (score 1):

**"Foundations of Statistical Natural Language Processing"** by Christopher D. Manning and Hinrich Schütze is a great book to start with. It contains an introduction to both basic linguistic concepts and probability theory.
The chapters about Markov chains and n-gram models really helped me to understand the subject.

Another classic textbook is **"Speech and Language Processing"** by Daniel Jurafsky and James H. Martin.

There are also two courses on Coursera: [one by Daniel Jurafsky and Christopher Manning](https://class.coursera.org/nlp) and [one by Michael Collins](https://www.coursera.org/course/nlangp). All three instructors are very well-known specialists in the field and both courses have great syllabus and cover topics you refer to.